# Azure bot responses to webhook

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

Is there a way for bot to send responses to my webhook?
Direct-line channel works fine but communication is done via websockets or via polling. I would like to have an option where bot sends responses to my rest api endpoint.

I've tried to create an adapter but in that case I have to manage all the conversations logic and incoming/outgoing messages.

What would be the best solution for this?

ps. I'm using bot composer to create bot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-box way to *additionally* send responses to your endpoint with Composer. You can use the `Send an HTTP` action in composer, but that is for specific and isolated calls.

> What would be the best solution for this?

Are you wanting to send all responses to your webhook? or just make calls to your webhook under certain scenarios?

I'm not sure i'm understanding the ask entirely, but if you are just wanting to send responses additionally to your endpoint (not changing the response back to the channel connector and client, etc), you could create [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Depending on your specific needs, you might even be able to utilize/inherit/customize the [inspection middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-inspection-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I want to send bot responses to end point. So everything that comes out from bot should go to endpoint. I've tried also middleware but it catches only user messages. Will give it a try with inspection middleware.



   ps. Incoming messages from user should use direct-line protocol, outgoing messages from bot should be sent to endpoint instead of websocket.

Comment: @Filip I'm in a the same position as you were. Would like to know if you solved and if yes, please can you post. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @bubi,
I've managed to solve it by creating my own Adapter which inherits from CloudAdapterBase and IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter. After that I register my adapter as singleton IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter.